# ICallbackEventHandler & Outlook Web App

Tags: javascript, asp.net, outlook-2010, outlook-web-app

I'm trying to use a [`ICallbackEventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.icallbackeventhandler.aspx) in a CustomForm in an OL 2010 Web App (OWA).

When I'm trying [this MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178210%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) the website (standard ASP.NET) works without a problem.

However applying the same example to my CustomForm doesn't result in anything useful. When the `CallServer(...)` js method is executed something happens and the page reloads. But js function `ReceiveServerData(...)` is never called.

I'm getting no errors whatsoever.

Can anybody tell me if ICallbackEventHandler can be used with OWA 2010? - If not, are there any workarounds?

Comment: I don't know the specific answer to the question, but have you tried using Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com) or a similar program to watch the request to and response from the web server? We use this extensively to resolve mystery issues like this.

Comment: No, we didn't go that far. Our workaround is to pass the data in hidden html fields. It's not the best solution, but since we only have a few hundred records and this functionality won't be used heavily it's not that big of a problem.